# Mi ListView no se muestra. (Java)

Tags: java, android, listview

**Hola buenas, me estoy iniciando en el mundo del `Android` y por alguna razón el `ListView` no me funciona, a ver si alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal.
Gracias de antemano.**

> Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Country[] paises;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listaPaises = findViewById(R.id.lvLista);
        CountryParser oPaises = new CountryParser(this);
        paises = oPaises.getCountries();

        CountryAdapter adaptador = new CountryAdapter(this, paises);
        listaPaises.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
}
```

> Adaptador personalizado

```
public class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {
    private Country[] paises;

    public CountryAdapter(@NonNull Context context, Country[] paises) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_country);
        this.paises = paises;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflador = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View item = inflador.inflate(R.layout.listitem_country, null);

        ImageView ivBanderas = item.findViewById(R.id.ivBandera);
        String codigo = paises[position].getCode().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
        //ivBanderas.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(getResouces().getIdentifier("drawable/" + codigo, "drawable", getPackageName())));
        //ivBanderas.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("_" + codigo));
        //ivBanderas.setImageResource(R.drawable.paises[position].getCode().split("_"));
        ivBanderas.setImageResource(R.drawable._id);

        TextView nombre = item.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
        nombre.setText(paises[position].getNombre());

        TextView capital = item.findViewById(R.id.tvCapital);
        capital.setText(paises[position].getCapital());

        TextView poblacion = item.findViewById(R.id.tvPoblacion);
        poblacion.setText(paises[position].getPoblacion());

        return item;
    }
}
```

**Supongo que tengo algún tipo de error en el adaptador o en el `Main`, pero llevo mas de 1 día buscándolo y no lo encuentro.**

Comment: ¿Qué error se produce exactamente? ¿Has comprobado si en el `Logcat` tienes alguno?

Comment: Esto sale en el logcat:

2021-10-18 18:55:57.466 27457-27508/com.example.listviewholder E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@e1a9f79
2021-10-18 18:55:57.467 27457-27508/com.example.listviewholder E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@e82f4be

Comment: /com.example.listviewholder W/.listviewholde: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
/com.example.listviewholder W/.listviewholde: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)

Comment: /com.example.listviewholder W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes asegurar que al recibir el array `paises`, este tenga elementos:

```
 public CountryAdapter(@NonNull Context context, Country[] paises) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_country);
        this.paises=paises;
        Log.i("CountryAdapter", "El array paises contiene " + paises.length + " elementos"); 
    }
```

Segundo, tu Adapter debe tener el método `getCount()` que retorna el numero total de elementos para ser desplegados en la lista:

```
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
     return paises.length;
   }
```

Comment: Ya lo tengo implementado, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Como te comentaba, debes asegurar que paises contiene información, revisa la edición que hice en el constuctor CountryAdapter()  que va a imprimir en el LogCat cuantos elementos recibes, si no tiene elementos no mostrará nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya he podido arreglarlo, tenía un problema en el parseador el cual no cogia lo datos.

Comment: Si siempre hay que asegurar que el Adapter recibe los datos, si no llegan getCount() retornara 0 y no se mostrarán los elementos@vicentroigsaval

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el `Adapter`, te faltan varios métodos reservados que te permitirán trabajar con tu `ListView`, además, deberías usar el `context` de tu actividad y no el que obtengas en el momento de usar el `LayoutInflater`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private Country[] paises;

    public CountryAdapter(@NonNull Context context, Country[] paises) {
        this.context = context;
        this.paises = paises;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return paises.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Country getItem(int position) {
        return paises.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflador = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey, tendré en cuenta esos metodos a posteriori, per de todas maneras, incluso cambiando el contexto, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya he podido arreglarlo, tenía un problema en el parseador el cual no cogia lo datos.

Comment: He estado dándole vueltas y no se me ocurría nada, acuérdate de publicar tu solución como respuesta, quizás le sirva a alguien con el tiempo.